# How can I make this struct instance volatile in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, volatile

I'm using a generic buffer .c/.h file. I want to create an instance that is qualified as volatile to use as a com buffer.

The following code shows the problem, the qualifier is lost?? when passing the buffer address to the member functions.

The code segment uses the 'const' qualifier as an example, I'm assuming 'volatile' would behave in same way. Using Rowley ARM GCC compiler.

```
typedef struct buff_t {
  char buffchar;
  int index;
  }buff;

void buff_init( buff *thisbuff ) {
  thisbuff->buffchar = 'x';
  thisbuff->index = 0;
  }


int main(void)
{

  buff memBuffer;
  buff const UARTBuffer;
  buff *buff_ptr;

  buff_ptr = &memBuffer;
  buff_init( buff_ptr );          /* struct elements initialized as expected */

  // UARTBuffer.buffchar = 'y';   /* this caught by compiler as error to read-only object */
  buff_ptr = &UARTBuffer;         /* compile warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type */
  buff_init( buff_ptr );          /* UARTBuffer elements also initialized, expected const??? */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code tries to modify a `const` structure object through pointer and hence invokes an       **Undefined Behavior(UB)**. In short it is invalid code. The only way to avoid such a scenario is not to write code which invokes an UB.
Note that compilers allow you to write such codes and shoot yourself in the foot(rather face) doesn't mean you should.If you have a gun it is your responsibility to use it judiciously.

To mark a variable as `volatile` you just need to add the keyword `volatile` during its declaration just similar to `const` in the program.

Comment: Thanks. But what I was trying to achieve is to instantiate the UARTBuffer as volatile (not all instances of buff, just the UART one). I was only testing with CONST qualifier to be able to verify the operation during runtime (seemed harder to verify VOLATILE behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Qualifiers are a property of each pointer, separately.

If an object is `const`, and you take a non-`const` pointer to it, it doesn't make the pointer `const`. The compiler may warn you, or you may crash trying to write to it (irrelevant for `volatile`), but the pointer won't be treated as `const`.

In your case, both `buff_ptr` and `buff_init`'s `thisbuff` should have the qualifier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I assumed that the 'const' qualifier would be a property of the declaration (ie. buff const UARTBuffer;) Then any further reference to UARTBuffer, even through a non-const pointer would still be treated as const. I want the data elements to be const, I don't care about the pointer variable. And I want to avoid qualifying 'buff_init's 'thisbuff' with qualifer because that would require ALL uses of buff to be 'const' <-- of course what I really want is 'volatile', but using 'const' I could see the data being changed, and hence the qualifier lost.

Comment: `const` has two effects. When defining a statically allocated variable, `const` may cause it to be in read-only memory (and may not). Then trying to write to it, no matter how, would fail at run-time. Also, when trying to write though a pointer declared `const`, the compiler will issue an error (even if the actual object isn't `const`). `volatile` only has a compile-time effect.